# Mvc 4 add controller with scaffolding giving error - "Unable to retrieve metadata..."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting an the following error when trying to add a controller with CRUD actions and EF:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for LetLord.Models.Tenant. Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of databases is not supported. Instead create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used.

Add Controller dialog settings:

**Template:** MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using EF.

**Model class:** Tenant (LetLord.Models)

**Data context class:** LetLordContext (LetLord.Models)

I've seen similar questions/problems, and tried the solutions offered but I **cannot** get it to work.

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LetLordContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|LetLord.Models.LetLordContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In `LetLordContext.cs` I don't have a default constructor. In my `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` class I call

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("LetLordContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

What I've tried:

- Change my provider name as described in different questions.
- Deleted the connection string **and** commented it out.
- Remove and reinstall Entity Framework.
- Ensure I have SQL Server CE 4.0 installed.
- Reverted back to an earlier version of my project on subversion.

I'm still at a loss, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have found a workaround, but I'm still oblivious to what was causing this error.

In the root web.config file I changed

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="LetLordContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|LetLord.Models.LetLordContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|LetLord.Models.LetLordContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This let me add views with scaffolding and once added, I changed the string back to what it was originally. As far as I'm aware any new string will do.

Comment: Also, you have to rebuild after you change the connection string name.

Comment: I presume it's some kind of bug, had me stubbed for a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is a bit heavy-handed, but after trying several solutions I had to get moving again. I decided to create a new model with a different name and copy the class internals into the new model. Then I selected the new Model in the "Add Controller" window and the scaffolding completed.

Then I deleted the old model.

No idea what was broken, but the new model worked fine.