# unable to retrieve metadata in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

My application is working fine.Now I added this model "LogOn.cs"

```
 public class LogOn
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
public class LogOnContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LogOn> LogOns { get; set; }
}
```

I build this app and now wanted to add controller,it look like this
[image]

When i press add button i am getting this error
[image]

What does this mean?What i missed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483860/mvc-4-add-controller-with-scaffolding-giving-error-unable-to-retrieve-metadat). May be this will resolve your problem:

In the root web.config file change the name of

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YourConnectionString" ...other code goes here...  </connectionStrings>
```

to:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" ...other code goes here... </connectionStrings>
```

Also, you have to **rebuild** after you change the connection string name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public class LogOn
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

 }
```

PS: What I normally do is create a empty controller and write the codes myself.